# Encontrar todas las raices de un polinomio de cualquier grado

Tags: javascript, math

Buen día, he estado buscando por distintos sitios web y no encuentro en el lenguaje que sea un programa que con un polinomio dado encuentre todas las raices, además que se sepa cual está repetida más de una vez y cual no, agradecería cualquier aporte, alguna idea o consejo de cómo hacer el programa. Gracias